# How will i input a value on database depending on the Select Option of HTML

Tags: mysql

I have a form in PHP where you select a type of Food through `dropdown select option` of html .

what i would like to know is that after i click the `submit`, It will add a row on `Table B` with the same value of NUM on Table A based on the Selected Food.

Table A

```
ID  FOOD   NUM
 01 Chicken 030
 02 Beef    031
```

Table B

```
ID  Name  Food    NUM
 01 John  Chicken  030
 02 Mary  Chicken  030
 03 Susan Beef     031
```

I tried the following codes but its not working. thank you for the help

```
$Cod_Food = htmlentities($_POST['Food_option'], ENT_QUOTES);
$sql ="UPDATE TableB INNER JOIN TableA ON TableA.Num= TableB.Num SET TableA.Num= TableB.Num WHERE TableA.Food = ".$Cod_Food.";";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your select box should have the IDs from table A as the values for the select options. This will let you store 01 instead of Chicken thousands of times and you can remove the NUM column from table B. It will save lots of space and be quicker to search if the table grows very large.

Second, `htmlentities` doesn't make data safe for databases. You should use PDO and parameters.

Third, your query is a bit wrong. You don't need the `JOIN` and you left out the `SET`. I believe it should look more like this:
`UPDATE tableB SET food = :food_id WHERE id = :person_id`